# How to construct an Error object. iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently writing a test unit for a class using Kiwi BDD framework. 
Here is the method that needs to be tested:

```
- (SFErrorType)typeForError:(NSError *)error {
    NSError *innerError = error.userInfo[SFInnerErrorUserInfoKey];
    if (innerError) {
        return [self typeForError:innerError]; 
    }
    return SFErrorTypeUndefined;
}
```

Method belongs to class SFErrorUtility.
SFErrorType - is a "typedef NS_NUM" that has 2 types - SFErrorTypeUndefined and SFErrorTypeAlert.

SFInnerErrorUserInfoKey is a NSString.

Question 1. Need to write a testing unit to test that method:

```
it(@" 6.6 should return [errorUtility typeForError:innerError] if innerError object can be created with userInfo - SFInnerErrorUserInfoKey", 
^{
    // something should be created here, probably an innerError object
    // my question is how to create this error object?  
    NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: something code:nil userInfo:nil];

    [[errorUtility typeForError:error] should] equal: [errorUtility typeForError:innerError]]; 
    }
);
```

Error's object consist of: 
  NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:(NSString*) code:(NSInteger*) userInfo:(NSDictionary*)];

We have a clue from method implementation about error's "userInfo" parameter. But I don't understand how we can use that in order to create our own error object. 
I in general don't understand what happens in this line of code:

```
    NSError *innerError = error.userInfo[SFInnerErrorUserInfoKey];
```

Question 2. We create a pointer by asking an error object its "userInfo" dictionary, whom we ask "what do you have inside under the "SFInnerErrorUserInfoKey" key? " Is that correct?

Question 3. Last question, isn't "userInfo" dictionary is private (read only)? Device constructs the "error" object himself, based on whatever error occurred. How come then we are assigning keys for it such as "SFInnerErrorUserInfoKey"?  There is probably some fundamental aspect that I don't understand.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you asking how to pass the `userInfo` of one `NSError` instance to a new one that you are creating?

Comment: Explain ur question in more details

Comment: For the test unit, I need to create an error object because it is being passed as an argument for a method that I'm testing. To create an error object, I gather information from method's implementation. The first line of code in my question was from method implementation. It gives me some clue how to construct that error object that I need, the clue is "userInfo". What I don't understand is how I can take that clue and create a standalone error object.

Comment: Show some relevant code so we can see what you have. Add a comment indicating what you are trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use [OCMock](http://ocmock.org/) and do something like this:

```
id errorMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[NSError class]];
[[[errorMock stub] andReturn:@"YourErrorDomain"] domain];
[[[errorMock stub] andReturnValue:@1] code]; //some error code
[[[errorMock stub] andReturnValue:@{@"expectedKey":@"expectedValue"}] userInfo];    

[sut yourMethodFailWithError: errorMock];
```

Hopefully this helps because I've only guessed your problem.

Comment: I'm required to use Kiwi BDD framework. Now sure if i can create OCMock objects there.